# how to force sqlmetal to keep field name case?

Tags: linq, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, sqlmetal

When dbml file is generated automatically by Visual Studio I get the exact field names as they appeared in the tables.

However, since VS does not provide refresh function for dbml, I run sqlmetal manually to re-create dbml file. It works fine with one exception -- sqlmetal "corrects" the names

```
ses_Id -> Ses_Id
aga_Id -> Aga_Id
```

and so on -- it probably changes camelCase to CamelCase.

Sqlmetal help does not list any switch to keep field names as-is (there is only pluralize switch). So, does anyone know the hidden switch to keep the case of field name?

Thank you in advance.

### SOLVED

There is no such switch, and MS was notified about the problem -- the wish report to add such feature (because it casuses problem with updating project) was closed as wontfix :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt there is a hidden switch. I had the same problem, so I wrote a simple Perl script to sort it out:

```
# Usage: fdbml.pl in.dbml out.dbml
my $in_file = $ARGV[0];
my $out_file = $ARGV[1];

# Scrape in file for identifiers
my @identifiers;
open IN, "<$in_file";
while (<IN>) {
    if ($_ =~ /<Table Name="(?:\w+\.)?(\w+)" Member="(\w+)"/) { push @identifiers, "$1 $2"; }
    if ($_ =~ /<Function Name="(?:\w+\.)?(\w+)" Method="(\w+)"/) { push @identifiers, "$1 $2"; }
}
close IN;

# Translate in file to out file
open IN, "<$in_file";
open OUT, ">$out_file";
while (<IN>) {
    my $line = $_;

    # Replace identifiers
    foreach my $identifier (@identifiers) { 
        my ($new, $old) = split(' ', $identifier);
        $line =~ s/"$old((?:Result)?)"/"$new$1"/g;
    }   
    $line =~ s/<Parameter Name="(\w+)" Parameter="\w+"/<Parameter Name="$1" Parameter="$1"/;

    print OUT $line;
}
close OUT;
close IN;
```

Just save all that  to fdbml.pl, make sure you have ActiveState Perl installed, then run this on your DBML file:

```
fdbml.pl old.dbml new.dbml
```

Ben

Comment: It appears a lot of people write dbmlhacker wrappers :-) I wrote mine too -- it deals with this problem and others too (like adding notifications on value set, not only changed).

Comment: Yep! This chunk of Perl script is only a cut down version to answer your question. My complete script also fixes the problem that when a stored proc returns a set of records via a SELECT, the primary key and other NOT NULL columns appear as Nullable<> types in the DataContext.